# DefaultIfEmpty behavior specifics

Tags: c#, linq

Recently I've met the issue, which took some time to figure out. I have such piece of code:

```
private Member FindMemberByName(string name)
{
    var member =
        this.db.Members.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(d => d.ShortName == name)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(this.CreateNewMember(name))
        .First();
    return member;
}

private Member CreateNewMember(string name)
{
    return this.db.Members.Add(new Member { Name = name });
}
```

I expected FindMemberByName() to return existing entity and in case of absence create new entity and return one.

However I have noticed CreateNewMember() was called even when existing name was passed.

Comment: I'd rather use the pattern `FirstOrDefault() ?? CreateNewMember`, which is a micro-separation of concerns.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you are asking about has nothing to do with LINQ.  The method you are placing in the DefaultIfEmpty() parameter list is going to be evaluated before DefaultIfEmpty() is ever called.  You can see this by coding up a similar method that makes no references to the default object being passed in.

```
void Main()
{
    CalledMethod(CreateDefault("Hello World"));
}

void CalledMethod<TSource>(TSource defaultValue)
{
}

TestClass CreateDefault(string message)
{
    return new TestClass() { Message = message, };
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Message { get; set; } = null;
    public TestClass() { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After debugging a little I've understood the value of `DefaultIfEmpty()` parameter is evaluated immediately even if no `First()` method is called. So in fact it's evaluated before understanding whether resulting IEnumerable is empty or not.

I've spent several hours trying to figure out the issue. Hope this would help others to save same amount of time :-)

Comment: Please move your answer out of the question and into the answer.  (Self-answering questions is okay, but should be done in the proper question/answer format.)